# SWIG installation troubles

Tags: path, pycharm, swig, openai-gym

I'm trying to get started doing some tensorflow tutorials and I ran into this error when trying to add box2d to PyCharm: "error: command 'swig.exe' failed: None." Everything I've found so far says to install SWIG. I extracted the zip and added "E:\SWIG\swigwin-4.0.2" to the system Path variable. "swig -version" doesn't work in Command Prompt. And I still can't add box2d to my PyCharm project. I've tried some different versions of swig, and nothings working. I don't know what else to try. Send help plz.

Edit: Tried restarting pc as well as using a different drive. Still not working. I did notice that the directory I'm adding to Path disappears whenever I restart or try "swig -version" in Command Prompt.

Edit: Problem was that I wasn't pressing Okay on the system properties window and my Path directories weren't being saved (I think).

Comment: Did you reboot?  Environment variables are inherited from the parent process so rebooting makes sure all processes are updated.

Comment: Yeah. I've tried rebooting after adding the directory to the Path. After the reboot, the directory was removed from Path, which seems pretty odd to me.

Comment: I found out the problem. Windows doesn't save/apply the Path variables until you press Okay on the system properties window, not when you press okay on the environment variables window. I wasted so much time on this it's depressing.

Answer (score 1):

Windows doesn't save/apply the Path variables until you press Okay on the system properties window, not when you press okay on the environment variables window. I hope this saves someone from frustration.